# Xcode 7 show project navigator and symbol navigator in the one column?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Is it possible to split the Xcode 7 navigator column into to cells and display selected navigators in each?

i.e. I would like to have the project navigator in the top cell and the symbol navigator in the bottom cell.

I have reviewed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436526/xcode-4-simultaneous-viewing-of-project-navigator-and-debug-navigator-and-othe) for Xcode 4, I am asking now to see if there have been any advancements to the layout options available in Xcode 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no :\  I tried for a while to achieve the same thing.  Best thing you could do is use the hotkeys, Cmd+1 and Cmd+2.  Or if you are just using one or the other for reference, you can open a new Xcode window